# Rank of identically distributed random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be identically distributed random variables. Is it true that $P(X < Y) = P(X > Y)$?

Comment: Are they independent?

Comment: what is $P(X<Y)$?

Comment: They are not assumed to be independent. Indeed, if $X$ and $Y$ were exchangeable, it would be easy to prove the relation.

Comment: If you could have a uniform distribution over the whole real line you could have X=Y+1 . But this isn't so.

Comment: Maybe the case where Y is a function of X is sufficient to find a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without independence, the answer is: not always.

For example: consider the following joint probability distribution for $X$ and $Y$.

$$\begin{array}{cc|ccc} &Y&1&2&3\\ X&&&&\\\hline 1&&.3&.2&0\\
2&&.1&.1&.1\\ 3&&.1&0&.1
\end{array}$$

$X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution with probabilities of $1$, $2$, $3$ being $.5$,$.3$, and $.2$ respectively.

But $P(X>Y)=.2$, while $P(X<Y) = .3$.

---

Edit:
For a continuous example, take $X$ uniform on $[0,1]$ and $Y=X+0.1 \pmod{1}$.  Then $Y$ is also uniform on $[0,1]$, but $P(X>Y) = .1$, while $P(X<Y)=.9$.

Comment: Do you have an example where Y is a mere function of X?

Comment: Do you have a continous counterexample?

Comment: @Alephnull: Maybe tricky to find an example with the requirement that $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed.

Comment: @Alephnull.  I do not have a continuous counterexample off hand.  But I would lean toward a guessing that it is possible.

Comment: @Alephnull: I thought of a continuous counterexample, and $Y$ is a function of $X$!  I will edit to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

Take Y=X+1 (mod n) where X is uniformly distributed over the residues modulo n.